# Remove every second carriage return starting from line two

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a text file where I'd like to remove every second carriage return starting with line 2. 
So the carriage return should be removed in lines 2, 4, 6, etc.

The carriage return can is identifiable in Notepad++ with the `LF` character.

I know that I can find it with `\n` in advanced mode.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Regular Expression mode.  You will search for a carriage return (Windows uses \r\n as a carriage return), some text, and then another carriage return.  The replace with will give you back only the stuff in the parenthesis.  Make sure you run "Replace all" as I did not test on replacing one at a time.

```
Find what:     (\r\n.*)\r\n
Replace with:  \1
```

Comment: it will replace first carriage return, skip the second, replace third and so on. If you want to begin with second line's carriage return, add an empty line at the beginning of the document.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this instead:

```
Regex: (.*?)\r\n(.*?\r\n)
Replacement: \1 \2
```

Only the last line has to be edited manually.

Answer (score 0):

Put the cursor on the first blank line and record a macro.

- <kbd>Del</kbd> then <kbd>↓</kbd>.
- Stop recording.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-P for a few seconds

I had nice clean results page from my nmap run.